# Probability of pulling a word out of a bag of scrabble tiles

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a game of scrabble with my family, I was the first to pull my letters. On the first turn I pulled the letters PARENTS. We were debating the probability of this happening. I suggested it to be the product of the individual tile probabilities given the current count of tiles.

In a game of scrabble there are 100 tiles. There are 2 P’s, 9 A’s, 6 R’s, 12 E’s, 6 N’s, 6 T’s, and 4 S’s. As you draw tiles there’s less total tiles to pull from. So, consecutive tile drawings to spell PARENTS has the probability of

2/100 * 9/99 * 6/98 * 12/97 * 6/96 * 6/95 * 4/94

Or (if I punched this in my calculator correctly) a 1/(2.313 10e-9) chance

Is my math and reasoning correct? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you demand that you specifically pull the tiles to spell PARENTS in proper order your calculation is correct.  If you accept the tiles to spell PARENTS in any order, there are $7!=5040$ orders for the tiles, so your probability should be multiplied by that.  If you are willing to accept any seven letter word with distinct letters in any order, you should multiply by the number of such words.

It is quite common for people to see an event that seems very improbable, but is really an example of a class of events that is much larger.  Any individual event in the class would lead to the same astonishment, so you should compute the probability of any event in the class occurring.  It is usually hard to determine what the class is, however.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!